# Organizar fluxo de dados por padrão de strings

Tags: python, string, lista, web-scraping

Amigos, estou trabalhando num projeto de scraping. Em dado momento, capturo uma tabela na tela em formato de uma string gigante, mais ou menos assim:

lista = ('0004434-48.2010 \n UNIÃO \n (30 dias úteis) 03/07/2017 \n 13/07/2017 \n 0008767-77.2013 \n 2017 \n (10 dias úteis) 03/07/2017 \n 13/07/2017).

Lidei com isso dando um comando "split", tendo como parâmetro o "\n", o que fez a lista ficar assim:

lista = ['0004434-48.2010', 'UNIÃO', '(30 dias úteis) 03/07/2017', '13/07/2017', '0008767-77.2013', '2017', '(10 dias úteis) 03/07/2017', '13/07/2017']

Agora minha dificuldade é: o primeiro item da lista é o número de referência da linha da tabela. Ele identifica um determinado contrato, que vai até o item que contém a segunda data. Em seguida vem OUTRA linha (outro contrato) e os itens subsequentes pertencerão a este segundo contrato.

Dúvida: como posso separar isso? Pois ainda irei tratar a data, os contratos só serão "clicados" dentro de determinadas condições. Tentei montar um laço assim:

```
for x in range(len(lista)):
    if len(lista[x]) == 15: #identificar o processo
        organizaProcessos.append(lista[x])
```

Mas assim eu crio uma lista dos processos, sem os seus correspondentes itens, e quando tento aninhar outra lista dentro da variável "organizaProcessos", não funciona...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

([TL;DR](https://repl.it/J5ep))
Se eu entendi o que voce quer fazer:

```
lista = ['0004434-48.2010',
 'UNIÃO',
 '(30 dias úteis) 03/07/2017',
 '13/07/2017',
 '0008767-77.2013',
 '2017',
 '(10 dias úteis) 03/07/2017',
 '13/07/2017']

def chunks(_list, parts):
     for i in range(0, len(_list), parts):
         yield _list[i:i+parts]

for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks(lista, 4)):
    locals()["part{0}".format(i)] = chunk

print ('Primeira parte: ',part0)
print ('\nSegunda parte: ',part1)
```

**Output:**

```
Primeira parte:  ['0004434-48.2010', 'UNIÃO', '(30 dias úteis) 03/07/2017', '13/07/2017']

Segunda parte:  ['0008767-77.2013', '2017', '(10 dias úteis) 03/07/2017', '13/07/2017']
```

Ou seja, vc tera `n` (Dependendo de quantos contratos tiver na linha) listas de 4 elementos, ca lista representando um contrato, sendo o primeiro elemento a identficação do mesmo.

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/J5ep)

Comment: Amigo, estou te devendo uma grana já! kkkkkkkkkkk mto obrigado de novo!

Comment: Ahahah! Bom saber que estou ajudando. Considere dar o aceite e upvote. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use **parse()** de **dateutil.parser**, que testa se uma string é uma data ou não.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding: utf-8
from dateutil.parser import parse

def chunks(string):
    try:
        int(string)
        return False
    except:
        try:
            parse(string)
            return True
        except:
            return False

def split(string,num):
    c = 0
    i = 0
    list = string.split(' ')
    for x in range(0,len(list)):
        c += chunks(list[i])
        i += 1
        if c == num: break
    return list[0:i],list[i+1::]

string = '0004434-48.2010 \n UNIÃO \n (30 dias úteis) 03/07/2017 \n 13/07/2017 \n 0008767-77.2013 \n 2017 \n (10 dias úteis) 03/07/2017 \n 13/07/2017'
a,b = split(string,2)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Esse será o output.

```
['0004434-48.2010', '\n', 'UNIÃO', '\n', '(30', 'dias', 'úteis)', '03/07/2017', '\n', '13/07/2017']
['0008767-77.2013', '\n', '2017', '\n', '(10', 'dias', 'úteis)', '03/07/2017', '\n', '13/07/2017']
```

Perceba que eu posso inclusive trabalhar com um número variável de datas por linha.
Suponha que eu queira separar as linhas após a terceira data, ao invés de após a segunda.

Basta trocar

```
a,b = split(string,2)
```

por

```
a,b = split(string,3)
```

e o resultado será

```
['0004434-48.2010', '\n', 'UNIÃO', '\n', '(30', 'dias', 'úteis)', '03/07/2017', '\n', '13/07/2017', '\n', '0008767-77.2013', '\n', '2017', '\n', '(10', 'dias', 'úteis)', '03/07/2017']
['13/07/2017']
```